# Unexpected events emitted by Swift Combine PassThroughSubject

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm currently playing with Combine and SwiftUI and have built a prototype app using the MVVM pattern. The app utilises a timer and the state of the button controlling this is bound (inelegantly) to the view model utilising a PassThroughSubject.

When the button is pressed, this should toggle the value of a state variable; the value of this is passed to the view model's subject (using .send) which should send a single event per button press. However, there appears to be recursion or something equally weird going on as multiple events are sent to the subject and a runtime crash results without the UI ever being updated.

It's all a bit puzzling and I'm not sure if this is a bug in Combine or I've missed something. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Code below - I know it's messy ;-) I've trimmed it down to what appears to be relevant but let me know if you need more.

View:

```
struct ControlPanelView : View {
    @State private var isTimerRunning = false
    @ObjectBinding var viewModel: ControlPanelViewModel

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Case ID") // replace with binding to viewmode

            Spacer()
            Text("00:00:00") // repalce with binding to viewmodel

            Button(action: {
                self.isTimerRunning.toggle()
                self.viewModel.apply(.isTimerRunning(self.isTimerRunning))
                print("Button press")
            }) {
                isTimerRunning ? Image(systemName: "stop") : Image(systemName: "play")
            }

        }
//            .onAppear(perform: { self.viewModel.apply(.isTimerRunning(self.isTimerRunning)) })
            .font(.title)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 32, bottom: 0, trailing: 32))
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
final class ControlPanelViewModel: BindableObject, UnidirectionalDataType {

    typealias InputType = Input
    typealias OutputType = Output

    private let didChangeSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    let didChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

    // MARK:- Input
...
    private let isTimerRunningSubject = PassthroughSubject<Bool, Never>()
....


    enum Input {
...
        case isTimerRunning(Bool)
...
    }
    func apply(_ input: Input) {
        switch input {
...
        case .isTimerRunning(let state): isTimerRunningSubject.send(state)
...
        }
    }

    // MARK:- Output
    struct Output {
        var isTimerRunning = false
        var elapsedTime = TimeInterval(0)
        var concernId = ""
    }
    private(set) var output = Output() {
        didSet { didChangeSubject.send() }
    }

    // MARK:- Lifecycle
    init(timerService: TimerService = TimerService()) { 
        self.timerService = timerService

        didChange = didChangeSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()

        bindInput()
        bindOutput()
    }

    private func bindInput() {
        utilities.debugSubject(subject: isTimerRunningSubject)

        let timerToggleStream = isTimerRunningSubject
            .subscribe(isTimerRunningSubject)

...

        cancellables += [
            timerToggleStream,
            elapsedTimeStream,
            concernIdStream
        ]
    }

    private func bindOutput() {
        let timerToggleStream = isTimerRunningSubject
            .assign(to: \.output.isTimerRunning, on: self)
...
        cancellables += [
            timerToggleStream,
            elapsedTimeStream,
            idStream
        ]

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm no expert, so please, take that into account. What caught my eye your button. Why is it updating *both* `isTimerRunning` *and*... something in your `viewModel`? Why not just (1) get rid of `apply` and the "local" update and instead (2) just directly update your `viewModel.isTimerRunning`? If you don't want to do it in your button action directly, then create a local `func` in your view and call it from there. Bottom line, why is your `ControlPanelView`'s `isTimerRunning` existing at all if the actual owner is the model?

Comment: I don't mind the "messy" code as you called it, but please consider adding the missing parts so that it can actually be compile and reproduced by others. That will increase your chances of getting a proper answer, and possibly a solution. Also note that a lot of times, creating a minimal example to showcase a problem, will lead you to a breakthrough. You may not even need to post your question in the first place when you do.

Comment: Thanks for you comments both - it’s useful feedback. 
Yes, the view model binding defeats the object of this pattern as it stands and may have introduced some unexpected behaviour. I’ll trying correcting this in the first instance on the off-change it resolves the issue. 
The suggestion of creating a minimal example is an excellent idea and I’ll certainly run within this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example works as expected but I discovered during the process that you cannot use the pattern in the original code (internal Structs to define Input and Output) with @Published. This causes some fairly odd errors (and BAD_ACCESS in a Playground) and is a bug that was reported in Combine beta 3.

```
final class ViewModel: BindableObject {

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

@Published var isEnabled = false

private var cancelled = [AnyCancellable]()

init() {
    bind()
}

private func bind() {
    let t = $isEnabled
        .map { _ in  }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        .subscribe(didChange)

    cancelled += [t]
}
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var viewModel = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        viewModel.isEnabled ? Text("Button ENABLED") : Text("Button disabled")
        Spacer()
        Toggle(isOn: $viewModel.isEnabled, label: { Text("Enable") })
    }
    .padding()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `bindInput` method `isTimerRunningSubject` subscribes to itself. I suspect this is not what you intended and probably explains the weird recursion you are describing. Maybe you're missing a `self.` somewhere?

Also odd is that both `bindInput` and `bindOutput` add all streams to the `cancellables` array, so they'll be in there twice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I created a 'bare bones' demo that doesn't suffer from recursion (will try and attach) but your suggestion seems the most likely. With regards to the cancellables array, you have to keep a reference to the publishes to keep them in scope (and it also gives you a 'handle' to cancel things if needed) so I believe that's OK. I tend to think of it a bit like RxSwift's DisposeBag

Comment: Yes, but if you add them in both `bindInput` and `bindOutput` they'll be added twice. In the code you've shown it's an array. Perhaps DisposeBag is some sort of Set in RxSwift (sorry not familiar with RxSwift)

Comment: Yes, you're correct but I think the self-subscribe is the source of the recursion, not the cancellables array. Not my finest piece of code! :-)

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure you knew the implications (with the array). As regards Combine -- we're all learning... Good luck with your project!